Deploying Teams Toolkit app via CI/CD fails with 'This command only works for project created by Teams Toolkit' error
My MS Teams app (a chatbot) provisions, deploys and runs fine locally, in testtool and in Azure.
So I've decided to finally take it that one step further and set CI/CD up as well, since I have it set up for all my other projects. However, it's the first time for me setting CI/CD up for Node.js project.
I'm following these instructions on how to set up pipeline with Azure DevOps, but the deployment step fails when executing npx teamsapp deploy command with the following:
Starting: Deploy to Azure
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.237.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/45easss6-ddd-4c39-9b3c-xxx.sh
(✖) Error: coordinator.InvalidProjectError: This command only works for project created by Teams Toolkit.

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Deploy to Azure


My teamsapp.yml is pretty standard for a Teams Toolkit app, so I'm not sure why would the deployment script consider the project not being created by Teams Toolkit?
YAML pipeline code used:
trigger:
  - dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  TEAMSAPP_CLI_VERSION: 3.0.0

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "20"
      checkLatest: true

  - script: |
      npm install @microsoft/teamsapp-cli@$(TEAMSAPP_CLI_VERSION)
    displayName: "Install CLI"

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp auth login azure --username $(AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_ID) \
      --service-principal true \
      --tenant $(AZURE_TENANT_ID) \
      --password $(AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_SECRET) \
      --interactive false
    displayName: "Login to Azure by service principal"

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp deploy \
      --ignore-env-file true \
      --interactive false
    displayName: "Deploy to Azure"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp package
    displayName: "Package app"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appPackage/build/appPackage.zip
    artifact: artifact

My teamsapp.yml:
# Triggered when 'teamsfx deploy' is executed
deploy:
  # Run npm command
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    name: install dependencies
    with:
      args: install
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    name: build app
    with:
      args: run build --if-present
  # Deploy your application to Azure App Service using the zip deploy feature.
  # For additional details, refer to https://aka.ms/zip-deploy-to-app-services.
  - uses: azureAppService/zipDeploy
    with:
      # Deploy base folder
      artifactFolder: .
      # Ignore file location, leave blank will ignore nothing
      ignoreFile: .webappignore
      # The resource id of the cloud resource to be deployed to.
      # This key will be generated by arm/deploy action automatically.
      # You can replace it with your existing Azure Resource id
      # or add it to your environment variable file.
      resourceId: ${{BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID}}


Please edite your post and paste the yaml code here, instead of adding a link to Github.

If you run npx teamsapp deploy in the directory of your local repo, will the issue be reproduced?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I've tried running npx teamsapp deploy in my project's directory (same where I run all project related npm commands from) and this is what I get:
npm error code E404 npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/teamsapp - Not found npm error 404 npm error 404  'teamsapp@*' is not in this registry. npm error 404 npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

I created a simple Teams app project and provisioned the Azure resources for deployment via pipeline. Please compare the file structure in my sample below and modify the workingDirectory property for your npx teamsapp deploy script accordingly.

Generally speaking, the CI/CD workflow via Azure Pipelines introduced in this document is running Teams Toolkit CLI in script tasks to authenticate access to Azure and deploy the Teams app project to Azure Web App.
Please note that the root directory of your repo will be checked out into the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) on the pipeline agent machine; expanded as /home/vsts/work/1/s/ on a Microsoft-hosted ubuntu-latest agent machine.
You haven't shared the file structure of your repo. Here is my sample repo and YAML pipeline to deploy my ChatBot Teams app for your reference.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  TEAMSAPP_CLI_VERSION: 3.0.0
  TEAMSFX_ENV: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID: /subscriptions/$(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)/resourcegroups/$(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$(AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME)

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "20"
      checkLatest: true

  - script: |
      npm install @microsoft/teamsapp-cli@$(TEAMSAPP_CLI_VERSION)
    displayName: "Install CLI"

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp auth login azure \
        --username $(AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_ID) \
        --service-principal true --tenant $(AZURE_TENANT_ID) \
        --password $(AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_SECRET) \
        --interactive false
    displayName: "Login Azure by service principal"

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp deploy --ignore-env-file true --interactive false
    displayName: "Deploy to Azure"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  - script: |
      npx teamsapp package --env $(TEAMSFX_ENV)
    displayName: "Package app"
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/appPackage/build/appPackage.$(TEAMSFX_ENV).zip
    artifact: artifact



Since Azure Pipelines are only an automation tool, please make sure your Teams Toolkit CLI works before integrating those commands in a pipeline.

Thank you, Alvin. Like I've responded to another comment, I've checked the content of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) with tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /f and the .yml file can be found where, I believe, it should be: /home/vsts/work/1/s/ChatBot/teamsapp.yml? Thank you!

Thank you Alvin. I've changed line workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ChatBot and that solved the issue.

The error means that the 'teamsapp.yml' not found in the current directory where the command executes. Can you make sure the ./teamsapp.yml path is accessable relative to the npx command execution directory?

Thank you. I've checked the content of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) with tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /f and the .yml file can be found where, I believe, it should be: /home/vsts/work/1/s/ChatBot/teamsapp.yml? I would expect this command to find it easily as it's a standard configuration?
